# What USB driver should we use for the Nexus 5?

Tags: android, google-nexus

As of the time of this writing, Google does not provide a USB driver (for Windows) for the Nexus 5. The usual link (http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) shows Windows USB drivers for several of the Nexus's line. However, the "Nexus 5" is not included. Note that the Nexus "**S**" (letter-**S**, not number-**5**) IS supported.

Also, from this site, the latest version of the current download is version-8, July-17-2013. When I compare this with its predecessor, version-7, the files are the same.

Until Google fixes this, what are we to do? How can we debug and develop for the Nexus 5?

Comment: The reason there is no new driver is that starting with the driver version 8, the driver should be the *same* for all new devices. I'll have the doc updates to reflect that.

Comment: I managed to enable ADB and MTP on WinXP by installing:
<br>
1. Wumdf 1.0 drivers (without these the following steps fail)
2. Google USB drivers (ver 8.0)
3. LG USB drivers

With this combo, I can do MTP file transfers when USB debug mode is off (why only when off?). However, when I enable USB debug mode, MTP driver is listed as 'misconfigured'

Frustrating..........

Comment: We updated the page at http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html to clearly state that all Nexus devices are covered by the Google USB Driver, and also to state that it is needed only for ADB. The Nexus 5 is supported, and if you only need to transfer files you do not need the driver. If you still have issues, please file bugs on http://b.android.com.

Comment: Update: This might be slightly unrelated but if you have a case where your Nexus device is recognized by the Device Manager and NOT by ADB, try this: http://b.android.com/62365#c7

Comment: @ralfatandroid - While we appreciate the help, your edit completely overwrote the original question and made it nonsensical. I've tried to convert this into a more generic question, and I recommend taking what you edited into the question and converting that into an answer. In the meantime, I've rolled back the core of the question, stripped out the ranty bits, and reopened it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, because it is really about a user-level problem.

Comment: @ralf, its really an annoying issue. I tried to copy music from my brand new windows 7 into my brand new nexus 5. but when I connect via USB I'm getting "MTP USB Device: Failed error".

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I have a solution.

I updated the file **android_winusb.inf** to reflect the **VID** and **PID** of the **Nexus-5**. Now it loads the generic driver and supports [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) in Eclipse.

Note, after any previous attempts you may have made, go to [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) and update the driver for the "Nexus 5" (showing with a yellow exclamation mark).

You have to navigate over to the [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) driver directory, which on my machine was:
**C:\Users\Xxxxxxxxx\android-sdk\extras\google\usa_driver**

In that directory, edit file **android_winusb.inf** in both the x86 and amd64 sections and insert one line:

```
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE1&MI_01
```

This was enough for me to get this to work.

Here is the content of my file:

```
;
; Android WinUsb driver installation.
;
;
;
; Includes FIX for the Nexus-5 ADB,
;                  --- jonovos         ---
;                  --- petuniaPlatypus ---
;                  --- 2013-11-07      ---
;
;        By snooping on the USB for the Nexus-5,
;        it is known that the VID = 18D1 and PID = 4EE1.
;        With this, we insert them into the GENERIC sections bwlow.
;
;
[Version]
Signature           = "$Windows NT$"
Class               = AndroidUsbDeviceClass
ClassGuid           = {3F966BD9-FA04-4ec5-991C-D326973B5128}
Provider            = %ProviderName%
DriverVer           = 07/09/2013,8.0.0000.00000
CatalogFile.NTx86   = androidwinusb86.cat
CatalogFile.NTamd64 = androidwinusba64.cat

[ClassInstall32]
Addreg = AndroidWinUsbClassReg

[AndroidWinUsbClassReg]
HKR,,,0,%ClassName%
HKR,,Icon,,-1


[Manufacturer]
%ProviderName% = Google, NTx86, NTamd64


[Google.NTx86]

;Google Nexus One
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E12&MI_01

;Google Nexus S
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E21
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E22&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E23
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E24&MI_01

;Google Nexus 7
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E40
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E42&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E44&MI_01

;Google Nexus Q
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_2C10
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_2C11

;Google Nexus (generic)
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE0
;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-new-line-added:
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE1&MI_01
;;;;;;;;
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE4&MI_02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE6&MI_01


[Google.NTamd64]

;Google Nexus One
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E12&MI_01

;Google Nexus S
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E21
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E22&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E23
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E24&MI_01

;Google Nexus 7
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E40
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E42&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E44&MI_01

;Google Nexus Q
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_2C10
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_2C11

;Google Nexus (generic)
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE0
;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-new-line-added:
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE1&MI_01
;;;;;;;;
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE4&MI_02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE6&MI_01

[USB_Install]
Include = winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT

[USB_Install.Services]
Include     = winusb.inf
AddService  = WinUSB,0x00000002,WinUSB_ServiceInstall

[WinUSB_ServiceInstall]
DisplayName     = %WinUSB_SvcDesc%
ServiceType     = 1
StartType       = 3
ErrorControl    = 1
ServiceBinary   = %12%\WinUSB.sys

[USB_Install.Wdf]
KmdfService = WINUSB, WinUSB_Install

[WinUSB_Install]
KmdfLibraryVersion  = 1.9

[USB_Install.HW]
AddReg  = Dev_AddReg

[Dev_AddReg]
HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs,0x10000,"{F72FE0D4-CBCB-407d-8814-9ED673D0DD6B}"

[USB_Install.CoInstallers]
AddReg    = CoInstallers_AddReg
CopyFiles = CoInstallers_CopyFiles

[CoInstallers_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000,"WdfCoInstaller01009.dll,WdfCoInstaller","WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll"

[CoInstallers_CopyFiles]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll

[DestinationDirs]
CoInstallers_CopyFiles=11

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\i386
2 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\amd64

[SourceDisksFiles.x86]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll  = 1
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll = 1

[SourceDisksFiles.amd64]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll  = 2
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll = 2

[Strings]
ProviderName                = "Google, Inc."
SingleAdbInterface          = "Android ADB Interface"
CompositeAdbInterface       = "Android Composite ADB Interface"
SingleBootLoaderInterface   = "Android Bootloader Interface"
WinUSB_SvcDesc              = "Android USB Driver"
DISK_NAME                   = "Android WinUsb installation disk"
ClassName                   = "Android Device"
```

Comment: When you get PID=4EE1, do you have ADB enabled in developer tools? Normally the PID 4EE1 is for MTP only (without ADB) for file transfer (in which case you do NOT need any driver as Windows 8 should handle this transparently), and PID 4EE2 is for MTP+ADB. The USB driver is only useful for ADB, not for simple MTP or PTP usage.

Comment: PID=4EE1 is what you get when you use the N5 in MTP (media transfer protocol, to access files) without activating ADB at the same time. Windows 7 and 8 have native support for this and no driver is required. Windows XP supports MTP if you install Media Player 10. You actually do **not** want to define PID=4EE1 in the Google USB driver otherwise it might prevent Windows from using its native MTP driver (this was the issue with the driver in version 7, which we fixed in version 8.)

Comment: Can anyone confirm this works on Windows 8? I get a message telling me that the file doesn't have a hash and that it has been tampered with and therefore won't update the drivers.

Comment: @Syntax try Alex B's answer instead.

Comment: Nexus 5 USB Debugging only works in Camera (PTP) mode for me... I don't know why.

Comment: My N5 is listed as PID_4EE2 so i added:
;Google Nexus5
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&MI_01

Comment: @PetuniaPlatypus it gives me **The hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file. The file is likely corrupt or the victim of tampering.** error. I disabled device driver signing check (*run `BCDEDIT /set nointegritychecks OFF` in cmd*) but still.

Comment: @tchelidze The following worked for me: https://www.dinolite.us/support/using-older-models-with-windows-8-10

Answer (score 113):

I just wanted to bring a small contribution, because I have been able to debug on my Nexus 5 device on Windows 8, without doing all of this.

When I plugged it, there wasn't any yellow exclamation mark within [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager). So for me, the drivers were OK. But the device was not listed within my [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html). After a little bit of searching, it was just an option to change in the device settings. By default, the Nexus 5 [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) computer connection is in [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) mode (Media Device).

What you have to do is:

- Unplug the device from the computer
- Go to Settings -> Storage.
- In the ActionBar, click the option menu and choose "USB computer connection".
- Check "Camera (PTP)" connection.
- Plug the device and you should have a popup on the device allowing you to accept the computer's incoming connection, or something like that.
- Finally, you should see it now in the DDMS and voilà.

I hope this will help!

Comment: Awesome, this solved it for me, thank you very much, almighty972!

Comment: This worked for me too.  I've also seen this same issue on other devices, switching to PTP mode makes it show up in ddms.

Comment: Your post also solved the Nexus 5 USB problem for me. Perhaps it isn't "a small contribution". Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, no messing around with anything needed, just change a setting on the device

Comment: The lack of proper ADB+MTP support is what we fixed between driver revision 7 and 8. In version 7, the INF add an incorrect entry that made the MTP mode not work properly in some cases. Also note that on Windows XP, MTP is not part of the base OS (it's added by Media Player 10 though). Finally, if you update the Google USB driver from rev 7 to 8 and ADB still doesn't recognize the device in MTP mode, try the workaround that I've listed at http://b.android.com/62365#c7

Comment: +1 Doing this allowed me to install the drivers on Windows 8.1. I had to turn off driver verification from Windows Smart Screen but I was finally able to install it.

Comment: Small caveat: this did not work for me on Windows 7, possibly because I didn't read almighty972's comment that he was using Windows 8. :)  I used Alex B.'s solution below (download latest USB drivers from Google) and was successful.

Comment: I did this but also had to enable Development Options -> Revoke USB debugging authorisation.

Comment: @almighty972 I have "Media Device(MTP)" checked but still able to find the device in DDMS. I am in windows 8. Perhaps I am using USB driver version-8, that's why?

Comment: I think this is an issue with the Windows USB host driver, i have a Lenovo laptop and i did not need to swtich to "Camera" before but after an OS update i got this issue and i had to switch.

Comment: This worked for me, but the real problem is that I had an old version of the Google USB drivers (7.0.0.1). Setting to Camera should not be needed with the latest driver (8.0.0.0 or later). Windows 7 refused to install the newer version even if I tried to manually select the directory or .inf file. Had to manually delete cached .inf files in WINDOWS\inf folder, follow directions here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62365#c7

Comment: This was exactly the answer that I needed. Worked exactly as described on Windows 8 and Visual Studio (Xamarin).

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @ralf at android, no it still doesn't work for me in MTP mode. Only Camera(PTP) works.

Comment: Worked Perfect for me

Comment: This solution worked for me even though there *was* a yellow exclamation mark next to the "Nexus 5" device in Windows 8.1's device manager.

Comment: I did it but I still got "No devices detected" on "chrome://inspect/#devices" when I wanted to debug my Nexus 5. So I installed the Google USB drivers with the Windows Device Manager and then it worked! :) Thank you! The path to the drivers was: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver".

Comment: Perfect answer. i was struggling from last 4 days

Answer (score 55):

This worked for me:

1. Download the Nexus 5 Drivers from *[Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)*
2. Extract the ZIP contents and place all files in a single folder on your desktop.
3. Connect your device to your computer.
4. Launch the Device Manager on your PC.
5. Now you should see the Nexus 5 listed in the hardware list.
6. Right-click the ‘Nexus 5′ line and then click on *Update Driver Software*.
7. Next, click the ‘browse my computer’ option.
8. In the new window, click on ‘Browse…’ button.
9. Go to folder unzipped at step 2. Select the folder where you extract the USB drivers. Click Next.

   - Make sure to tick the subfolder box too.
10. Now, the Windows installer will search for Nexus 5 drivers. Click *Install* when asked for permission.
11. Wait for the process to complete and then check the Device Manager list to confirm that the installation was successful.

Source: *[Download and Install Google Nexus 5 USB Drivers (ADB / Fastboot)](http://www.android.gs/download-and-install-google-nexus-5-usb-drivers-adb-fastboot/)*

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 8.1 (with USB debugging enabled).

Comment: Worked for me.  Additional Notes: 1)Make sure to enable USB debugging on phone (Settings->Enable Developer options (google this)->USB Debugging) 2)Make sure to allow connection on phone to computer (should get a popup on phone asking). If you don't unplug USB after installing driver, then reconnect.

Comment: Works for me. Both MTP on, Usb Debugging on. Inititally I used it with MTP off, and it couldn't work.

Comment: this worked for me, but downloading with SDK didn't worked so I downloaded the zip manually.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 8.1 - Thanks! I had "USB Debugging" enabled & my USB connection mode was set to "Camera (PTP)".

Answer (score 13):

My Nexus 5 is identyfied by the id = USB\VID_18D1&PID_D001.

Use the Google [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) drivers, and modify file `android_winusb.inf`. Find the lines:

```
;Google Nexus (generic)
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE0
```

And add below:

```
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_D001
```

Repeat it, because there are two sections to modify, `[Google.NTx86]` and `[Google.NTamd64]`.

If you continue with problems, try this:

Connect your Nexus 5, go to [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager), find the Nexus 5 on "other" and right click. Select properties, details, and in selection list, and select hardware id. Write down the short ID, and modify the line with:

```
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, YOUR_SHORT_ID
```

Comment: This worked for me! For my Nexus 5, the hardware id is `USB\VID_18D1&PID_D002` so I put:

`%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_D002`

Comment: Same here, `USB\VID_18D1&PID_D002`

Comment: After the OTA Update to Android L, i have to cahnge it again:
`USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE7`

Comment: Downvoting for link to wikipedia USB article. I think everyone in SO knows what a USB is or Device Manager in fact!

Answer (score 10):

I found a solution in *[How I fixed the MTP issues on Nexus 7](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=35854664&postcount=7)*.

---

Another way of fixing this on Windows 8: This problem may happen, because you have the Google [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) driver from the Android SDK installed. Windows will pick the ADB driver over the [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) driver, even when USB debugging is turned off on the Nexus 7. It also comes back when you upgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1. To fix this:

1. Plug the Nexus 7 in and make sure USB mode is set to MTP
2. Run devmgmt.msc
3. Locate the ADB driver, which may be under "Android Devices" or "ADB Devices"
4. Right-click on it and select "Update driver software"
5. "Browse my computer for driver software"
6. "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"
7. With "Show compatible hardware" checked you should see two drivers under "Model":
8. "Android ADB Interface"
9. Either "MTP USB Device" or "Composite USB Device"
10. Select "MTP/Composite USB Device" (that is, the one that isn't "Android ADB Interface") and click Next.
11. The device should now appear as an MTP device.

It was confirmed working with the Nexus 7 2013 as well.

Comment: This worked for me for Nexus 5 & Windows 8.1. Thanks.

Comment: Plus one thousand hundred million. Why isn't this documented on DAC?? I've been searching for the reason for this for SO. LONG.
Fixed the issue on my N5

Comment: Good lord thank you very much! Your solution works where every other fail.

Answer (score 3):

I installed the [LG United Mobile Driver](http://www.lg.com/us/mobile-phones/TMUS_Update/documents/LGUnitedMobileDriver_S4981MAN37AP22_ML_WHQL_Ver_3.7.2.exe), and I was finally able to get ADB to recognize my device.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems as people here with Nexus 5 on Windows 7. No .inf file edits were needed, my computer was stuck on an old version of the Google USB drivers (7.0.0.1). Windows 7 refused to install the newer version even if I tried to manually select the directory or .inf file. Had to manually delete specific cached .inf files in WINDOWS\inf folder, follow directions here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62365#c7

Also be sure USB debugging is turned on in developer options. There's a trick to expose the developer options, click 7 times on the build number at the bottom of the "About Phone" information!

Answer (score 2):

There are **multiple hardware revisions of Nexus 5**. So, the accepted answer doesn't work for all devices (it didn't work for me).

1. Open Device Manager, right click and *Properties*. Now go to the "Details" tab
   And now select the property "Hardware Ids".
   Note down the PID and VID.
2. Download [the Google driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)
3. Update the android_winusb.inf with above VID and PID

   ```
   %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&**PID_4EE1**
   ```
4. Now in Device Manager, find Nexus 5, and update the driver software, and browse to the location where you downloaded.
5. The driver should be installed, and you should be see the device in [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge).

Comment: This is tested on Nexus 5 and Nexus 4.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too. In the [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) all drivers were OK, but [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) couldn't find the device. Even after updating the Google USB drivers with the SDK Manager.

The problem was that I didn't have the developer options enabled. For that I came here, [How to Enable Developer Options on the Nexus 5 & KitKat](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/11/10/enable-developer-options-nexus-5-kitkat/).

Then I had to manualy update the Google USB drivers, see *[Download and Install Google Nexus 5 USB Drivers (ADB / Fastboot)](http://www.android.gs/download-and-install-google-nexus-5-usb-drivers-adb-fastboot/)*.

After that, my installation of Eclipse recognized my device.

Answer (score 1):

I was lost at first as well but found a fairly easy solution. Please note that I did all this on Windows 7 after enabling Developer Options and USB debugging on my Nexus 5 (on 4.4.2), then connecting it to my PC via USB.

If you go to the download link - http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html - you'll notice at the bottom in step 4, the installation location of the driver. If you then navigate to Devices and Printers from Control Panel and find your device, right-click and go to properties, then click the Hardware tab at the top, click the device displayed that is having issues, click properties, then Change settings. Next, select Update driver, choose the location manually, and choose the directory Google noted as the installation directory, which they noted as \extras\google\usb_driver\

This fixed the problem for me and my Nexus 5 now appears in DDMS.

Answer (score 1):

## This answer is for those with windows 8.1N! (and maybe all N versions)

The short answer is install **[Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 8.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40744)**

Big thanks to Matej Drolc that had it solved in hit blog post [here](http://pingec.si/blog/articles/windows-8.1-N-Nexus5-MTP-not-working-/).

Comment: Same for Win7 N, here is the media feature pack for Win7 N versions https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=16546

Answer (score 0):

While Nexus 5 owners wait for a dedicated driver, you could try [this driver](http://tool.xcdn.gdms.lge.com/dn/downloader.dev?fileKey=UW00120120425), which is the one for the [LG G2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LG_G2), from [LG Electronics'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LG_Electronics) website, since usually USB drivers are not limited to one particular model. This one, for example, seems like a generic USB driver. You are prompted to download the same one for quite a few models on LG Electronics' website.

I hope this helps you ;)

Answer (score 0):

The one from *[Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)* worked fine for me on two machines (Windows 7 x64 on both). Once Windows failed to auto-install the driver, I just right-clicked on the phone in Device Manager, chose "update driver" and gave it the path that I'd unzipped that driver into.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the other solutions I was able to send [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) commands to the phone as long as it was booted into Android. However, when the phone was in recovery mode I encountered a new problem, and I would like to contribute my experience here.

While booted into Android the phone installed in Windows as a device named "Nexus 5".  After the phone was powered down and booted into recovery mode, the phone was still installed as "Nexus 5", but ADB could not detect the device. I had to manually force the driver from "Nexus 5" to the Google USB driver provided with the SDK or available from *[Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)*.

The .inf file has three devices available. I used "Android Composite ADB Interface" and everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows 8.1, and I tried everything from the other answers and nothing worked. Finally, I decided to try "Pick from a list of drivers" and found "LGE Mobile Sooner Single ADB Interface" under "ADB Interface". ADB.exe was finally able to find the Nexus 5 and sideload 4.4.1.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Everything else here failed for me initially (it kept coming up as an [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) device no matter how many times I uninstalled and restarted).

However, by going and enabling USB debugging, it worked. Just do this:

1. Uninstall the Nexus 5 driver
2. Disconnect from the computer
3. Enable developer options, see *[How to Enable Developer Options on the Nexus 5 & KitKat](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/11/10/enable-developer-options-nexus-5-kitkat/)*.
4. Enable USB debugging: Go to *Settings* -> *Developer Options* -> *USB Debugging*
5. Reconnect
6. It will probably fail to install all drivers. Go update the drivers as described in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a driver problem? A device that *isn't detected* probably has a hardware or firmware problem.  If it isn't detected, you won't hear the USB device detected chime. It might not be serious, e.g. some "USB" cables are really only *charging* cables. Try a USB cable that you know works for data, e.g. the one that came with the phone or one you use for connecting an external hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate N version and my Nexus 5 showed up with a yellow exclamation mark in Device Manager and none of the solutions here worked.

I verified that the phone reported itself as:

```
USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE1
```

Which doesn't work with the current (v11) of the Google USB driver.

But after enabling **Developer Options** and **USB debugging** on the phone  it identified itself as:

```
USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&MI_01
USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&REV_0232&MI_01
```

Which installs just fine.

So just enable Developer Options on your phone and retry the device install.