# Nexus 5 USB driver

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to develop and debug **Nexus 5 with ADT (based on Eclipse) in Windows 7 x64**.

As I connect Nexus 5, it appears in Windows in Explorer, so I can transfer files to/from Nexus. Next step I enable USB debugging in Developer options on the phone; the phone shows notification "USB debugging connected", device disappears from Explorer and Windows tries to install a driver and fails. In Device Manager I see Nexus 5 with exclamation mark icon in "Other devices". Then I select Update Driver Software in Device Manager for Nexus 5 > Browse My computer for driver software > provide path to the driver I downloaded from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html:
C:\Program Files\Android\usb_driver, check "Include subfolders" and click Next.

I get the message "**Windows could not find driver software for your device**". I tried all kinds of tricks suggested on Internet including this topic:
[What USB driver should we use for the Nexus 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838016/google-provided-a-usb-driver-for-the-nexus-5)

Nothing helps. Any idea how to force Nexus 5 to work on Windows?

Looks like Google released Nexus 5 without providing an updated driver (the last version is dated 07/09/2013, version 8.0 making it useless for developer on Windows platform.

Comment: Maybe this might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19839812/3025732

Comment: Indeed, Joel is correct, this is a duplicate of [Google provided a USB driver for the nexus 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838016/google-provided-a-usb-driver-for-the-nexus-5) which itself needs to be re-opened as a very much on-topic and important question that will doubtless be of issue to many others as Nexus 5 devices continuing to find their way into the hands of new developers.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Currently experienced this problem with my Nexus 5, when attempting to sideload latest 4.4.1 OTA update via stock recovery.

Solution:

1. Open Android SDK Manager (in console get to sdk directory then run tools\android)
2. Download/install latest USB drivers (under Extras).
3. In Windows Device Manager (devmgmt.msc), right click the Nexus 5 device and select Update Driver Software.
4. Browse My Computer for driver software > Android SDK Dir > Extras > usb_driver

Comment: I'm not sure what drivers you were talking about...I used this:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top

Comment: After many days of search - this was the only thing that worked! Thanks!

Comment: Another +1 to @AlexKapustian! Perhaps you should post that as an answer!

Comment: This didn't work for me, but this did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21392398/1317559

Comment: @RavenDreamer Or maybe you should read the question. He states he is trying to use those AlexKapustian mentions

Comment: For me the path to the usb driver was Android SDK Dir > Extras > **google** -> usb_driver

Answer (score 52):

I just wanted to bring a small contribution, because I have been able to debug on my Nexus 5 device on Windows 8, without doing all of this.

When I plugged it, there was no yellow exclamation mark within the device manager. So for me, the drivers was OK. But the device was not listed within my eclipse ddms. After a little bit of searching, It was just an option to change in the device settings. By default, the Nexus 5 usb computer connection is in MTP mode (Media Device).

What you have to do is:

1. Unplug the device from the computer
2. Go to Settings -> Storage.
3. In the ActionBar, click the option menu and choose "USB computer connection".
4. Check "Camera (PTP)" connection.
5. Plug the device and you should have a popup on the device allowing you to accept the computer's incoming connection, or something like that.
6. Finally you should see it now in the ddms and voilà.

I hope this will help!

Comment: worked for me but does that mean I can't use the phone in MTP mode? Seems strange, because that is how I normally work with my other devices.

Comment: The Camera PTP trick worked for me. How very odd, since nothing else in any combination of drivers worked at all!

Comment: Hey, I tried but I am getting this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884361/my-device-isnt-getting-detected-in-android-studio-driver-issue?noredirect=1#comment55534220_33884361

Answer (score 18):

Well @sonida's answer helped me but **Here I am posting complete step How I did it.**

***Change Mobile Device Settings:***

1. Unplug the device from the computer
2. Go to Mobile Settings -> Storage.
3. In the ActionBar, click the option menu and choose "USB computer connection".
4. Check "Camera (PTP)" connection.

[image]

[image]

***Download Google USB Driver:***

5 .Now go to http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top and download USB Drivers --> unzip folder.

[image]

***Install USB Drivers and Get Connected Device:***

6.Then Right click on My computer -->Manage --> Device Manager.

[image]

7.You should seed Nexus 5 in the list.

8.Right click on Nexus 5 --> Update Driver Software... --> Browse my computer for driver software

[image]

9.select the folder we downloaded/unzipped "latest_usb_driver_windows" and Next ...Ok.

[image]

10.Now you will see pop-up dialogue asking for Allow device --> Ok.

11 .That's it!! device is connected now, you can see in DDMS.

[image]

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: @NiteshVerma happy to help dear!!

Comment: respectable battery levels

Comment: This just saved my bacon.

Answer (score 4):

Is it your first android connected to your computer? Sometimes windows drivers need to be erased. Refer http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2512549

Comment: This worked for me also. I had a bunch of old Android phone drivers installed. Once I removed them, everything worked. I used the WegFresh Nexus Root Toolkit v1.8.0 and did the driver re-install: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1766475

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 x32
I found that no matter what I did, the driver being used dated back to 2006. It would not update, in fact Windows appears to be preferring the old driver to the new. I eventually found a way to sort it.

The Device Manager contains 'ghost' drivers that need to be deleted (if you have the same problem as I). To see them requires setting a variable in the registry, restarting and then deleting the likely redundant drivers.

Open the Device Manager from the command line use devmgmt.msc There are other ways, but this is easiest to describe. Currently it shows only 'current' drivers.

Open the System Properties box. Via Command line use sysdm.cpl

** Be aware that playing with area of your computer can break it. Back away if you are at all unsure of this. **

1. Open the Advanced tab, click Environmental Variables.
2. Under System Variables, click New.
3. Enter variable name devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices, under value enter 1.
4. Restart your computer.

Re-open the Device Manager, under view click Show Hidden Devices.

From here delete what you think are the problems then follow the advise you will have read elsewhere. On two seperate computers I have done this and found all I needed to do following this was download and install the standard google drivers as per user3079537's answer above. Good luck.

ref: http://www.petri.co.il/removing-old-drivers-from-vista-and-windows7.htm#

Answer (score 0):

You should install Google Drivers from: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top
That works for me every time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884361/my-device-isnt-getting-detected-in-android-studio-driver-issue?noredirect=1#comment55534220_33884361

Answer (score 0):

**Nexus 5 with Win7 x64**

-USB computer connection : Uncheck MTP and PTP

-Use a 2.0 USB port.

-Try to use the original USB cable.

Now device manager will detect nexus 5 as an androide device with ADB driver.