# Nexus 5 will not show in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, nexus-5

My new Nexus 5 will not show in Eclipse. I have tried every single solution on the internet for the last 3 hours. I have windows 8, not 8.1. I have a new HP Envy laptop. I am under a tight time-frame and need to get developing with this phone.

Allow usb debugging is checked. The drivers are up to date and downloaded from the Android developer site for Nexus 5. I have then gone into device manager and right-clicked -> update drivers -> browse -> gone to that usb-driver file in Android sdk, made sure include sub-directories is checked, then click finish. It installs. They are already up to date. Tried selecting choose from list. then selcting MTP USB device and installing. That's the only one that shows up as compatible for me.

I have switched from MTP USB connection to PTP USB connection.

I have reset the adb in the DDMS.

I have found my hardwareId in Device Manager and then added the correct lines of code into the android_winusb.inf file.

I have gone into Android SDK manager, and under extras installed "Google USB driver". Mine is rev 8. Is that okay?

After all that I have restarted my computer and the phone.

My phone has always been recognised by my computer without doing anything. It is just Eclipse that needs to recognise it.

**UPDATE:** Originally I was finding my Nexus 5 in the device manager under portable devices and when i updated drivers from here it had no effect. Just then it popped up under "Other" and i updated the drivers with some i found recommended online but it said at the end "Samsung drivers installed" and this is LG. Then now I see my Nexus popping up under "Android device" in the device manager. **EDIT** Actually it says Android composite ADB interface. My Nexus is not under "Other" anymore. It is only under portable devices. Now my phone is showing up in Eclipse. But it is status offline, and When i click to run my app, it is there, but i cannot press "OK", and the target is unknown with a warning. Maybe the solution now is to double check i download correct drivers, ones that don't say "Samsung".

Thanks.

Comment: "I have tried every single solution on the internet for the last 3 hours" -- unless you tell us what you tried, you are likely to get the same solutions again.

Comment: User universal adb driver installer dear. It is here:http://adbdriver.com/

Comment: @Adnan Thanks. It says "detected Android device list" and no devices are found so it won't install.

Comment: Try this : http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?s=5df9d0d4010f2022116d0669501ed4fc&attachmentid=2372977&d=1383666308

Comment: And acknowledge if it work.

Comment: @Adnan thanks, but is that the Nexus 4 version? I downloaded and extracted it, then went to device manager to install it to my Nexus 5. When done, it said "Windows found driver software for your device but encountered an error. Google Nexus 4 ADB Interface. The hash file is not present in the specified catalogue file. The file is likely corrupt or the victim of tampering."

Comment: @Adnan it is working now. I think it was due to your suggestion to install the ADB interface that it now showed up in the ADB devices. Then I could perform Aakash's last step. Thank you both for helping.

Comment: This crap shouldn't be this bloody hard! WTF. With the Google USB driver installed (I have ver. 9) this *SHOULD* be plug and play.

Comment: check out this link . this solved my problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343014/adb-doesnt-show-nexus-5-device/

Comment: I found [this link](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/10/installing-google-nexus-5-usb-drivers.html) very useful.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try these steps and see if the device is recognized.

First check if you have Developer Options in the Settings Menu of your device.

If not - (Please know that in flagship nexus devices running 4.2 and later Android OS this option is hidden by Google on purpose)

How to Enable developer options - Go to Settings --> About Phone --> Build Number (Tap the build number 7 times) this should enable your Developer Option

Turn on USB Debugging

Connect your Nexus 5 to your computer using the USB cable.

If at this point Eclipse do not recognize it. Try to start a command prompt on Windows by pressing Ctrl + R and type cmd and enter.

Navigate to where you have installed your Android SDK folder where you have your adb.exe.

For me this is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\`

Do a `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` - enter

then type `adb devices` while your nexus 5 is attached to your computer. this should restart the adb server killing any stale session. At this point you should receive instructions on your device about RSA fingerprint etc. Just accept it and Eclipse should be able to communicate with your device.

**Edit:**

You may need to install adb drivers after following aforementioned procedure. Download universal adb driver installer from [here](http://adbdriver.com/) and execute it. It would automatically detect your phone model and will install drivers.

Happy Coding..

Comment: Thanks the last step of this answer got it working. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: another solution can also be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22270178/803077

Comment: This universal installer says its incompatible with my Win 8 x64..Pls help

Comment: After hours of frustration....the universal ADB driver installer did it for me....I love you.

Answer (score 4):

For windows 8 64 bit

Download USB driver from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top 
Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
Select Devices in the left pane.
Locate and expand Other device in the right pane.
Right-click the device name (such as Nexus S) and select Update Driver Software. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
Select Browse my computer for driver software and go to the usb driver folder which downloaded from above provided link.
(or) 
if you installed usb driver from sdk manager. locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
Click Next to install the driver.

Follow the above steps this worked for me for more information visit here http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

Answer (score 1):

First, uninstall through the device manager and check the delete check box before reinstalling.

Then install from here:   \sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

It will now work.

Solution comes from this site: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Android_Applications_on_a_Physical_Android_Device_with_ADB