# Nexus 5 USB Driver not found

Tags: android, nexus-5, google-nexus

Hey I am trying to learn the Android SDK development from lynda.com.

They asked me to update my USB drivers.

I downloaded the driver unzipped it. And when I try to update it in the MTP mode it says

```
Device driver up to date
```

I searched around and found it updates in PTP mode. But it says:

```
Windows could not find driver software for your device
```

I tried the same thing on another computer and it worked perfectly.

Is it because I am not using USB 2.0 ?

PS: Tried all the methods mentioned here.
[Nexus 5 USB driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168898/nexus-5-usb-driver?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nexus 5 USB driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168898/nexus-5-usb-driver)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. The following solution from [teamandroid](http://www.teamandroid.com/2012/07/30/how-to-set-up-adb-fastboot-with-android-sdk/2/)  worked from me:

1. Open the "Device Manager"
2. Choose "Update Driver Software"
3. Select "Browse my computer for driver software"
4. **So far so good, but now select** "Let me pick from a list of device drivers from my computer"
5. Click the "Have disk" button
6. Select to the "android_winusb.inf" file from the SDK Driver (located in [SDK-ROOT]\extras\google\usb_driver)
7. Now select "Android ADB Interface"

There will be the usual warnings concerning "not trusted manufacturer" which I just ignored.
After that everything worked fine for me.

Hope this helps you as well!

Best

Tobias

Comment: This might work for some people. I explored this solution before. But really the whole problem was with my corrupted USB ports. I updated from windows 7 to 8. Thanks for the help anyways !

Comment: This was the only method that worked for me on Win 7.

Answer (score 0):

I am using nexus 5 too and have seen the adb driver not working from time to time. My solution is as follows(only for windows users):

1. Connect device go to Device Manager
2. Search for your device. It may be under Android Phone(usually at top) or in the USB peripherials or simply as Nexus
3. Right click the device Uninstall the driver.
4. Unplug the device
5. Plug the device wait for windows to configure drivers(MTP and some others). Then reinstall the adb driver downloaded from google as per their recommendations.

Comment: The problem i am facing is, its not really able to uninstall the drivers !

Comment: @Leero Try changing the usb port usually those at the back is directly connected to the motherboard and supply more power to the device so it is preferred

Comment: I am seriously fatigued trying all possibilities. I think it just wont work on my laptop. I have tried using the Adb driver installer also.
It worked on the other laptop :(

Comment: I am now using Linux for Android development and its far easier. Thanks for the help anyways !

Comment: well android is based on linux kernel so you wont require driver to work with linux has best drivers.