# My device isn't getting detected in android studio (driver issue)

Tags: java, android, string, performance, android-studio

**The problem:** My device isn't getting detected in android studio

**The solution:** Install the correct usb drivers

**The problem that arises to the solution:** I am not able to...and here are the details:

I have recently system wiped my computer due to slowness. This brings me back to the tedious task of setting up my computer for Android Studio. I have tried **everything** to get  the USB drivers to work in android studio, but for some reason, I can't update my USB driver:
[image]

Now, here is the annoying screen that always pops up when trying to update my usb driver:

[image]

My usb driver **is installed:**

[image]

This is pretty pathetic. I have tried everything. **I even tried to go into my computers bios and disable Intel xHCI.** I remember when I first started android, I had this same problem, and the solution was to do something in the computer's bios, but the problem still persists.

By the way, I have done lots of research on this topic, and this is a code 28, which means it doesn't have the correct drivers:

[image]

I have been on this for 3 hours now (3 HOURS!) and would really appreciate **any** help. How can I get my phone recognized on my windows 8 laptop? I have done it before, so I know my phone is compatible.

Comment: Just because you have a driver directory , doesn't mean the driver was set-up properly though.. you need to properly install said driver. Sometimes driver issues are tricky though, this is well-known.  I have been struggling with an apple KB , for eg

Comment: @Coffee What should I do to properly install the driver?

Comment: not sure off the top of my head. Might be a better match for SuperUser , because we're more focused here on programming Q's . I'd keep at it, you've obviously figured *some* things out, just keep hacking away -  I've been there

Comment: This is a prime example of why windows is the *least suitable* of the three *nominally* supported platforms for android devleopment

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, especially since so many people have this problem, and there are barely any answers on the internet

Comment: Do you have `<path>/.android/adb_usb.ini`? It should contain the USB vendor id (ie `0x0502`) for your device.

Comment: @mbmc I do not have the `adb_usb.ini` in my `.android directory`. What do I do now? Thanks

Comment: @mbmc Here is the folder: `C:\Users\ruchir\.android`

Comment: @mbmc Let me know if you need any more information. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: What is your device? Are you sure google USB driver is compatible with your device?

Comment: @AccessDenied For sure. I have done this entire process before I system wiped my computer. Before, it would work without a need to install anything special. I also remember that last time, I did something in my system bios...

Comment: Search for it on google "USB driver for <device model> not compatible". I had troubles with Nexus 5. And I was not alone. Search this problem for specific device model.

Comment: @AccessDenied But I am absolutely sure that there are no external USB drivers that I need. This is because I did this before once, and I didn't need anything. Do I need to give myself permissions in the bios or something? Do you think it could be anything else?

Comment: You are not right. I also did nothing until windows shipped update and nexus started detecting as Asus phone. Uninstall driver for your device and choose google usb driver during installation process.

Comment: Don't be sure. Search for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168898/nexus-5-usb-driver

Comment: What do you mean uninstall and choose google. Where should I do that?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553572(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23195441/1099716

Comment: What kind of device? If it's a regular phone / tablet, no need to add it in `adb_usb.ini`

Comment: @mbmc It is a hwawei phone

Comment: @mbmc What is `adb_usb.ini`

Comment: I remember installing the drivers with `pnputil -i -a something.inf` but it's hazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that you have virtualization on in the bios. This was a big issue for me last time... It can be called VT-x.

Next, make sure you have done what I have done in my question.

What I forgot to do was install the `android_winusb` file in the usb_driver folder. The path should be `sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`. In my case, `C:\Users\Ruchir\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

After doing that, go **back** to device manager and go to the install as path. At the bottom of that should be another option:

Let me pick from a list of devices on my computer

Select your android phone, it shouldn't have a yellow explamation point over it any more. After that, select `composite ADB Interface`. THATS IT.

Answer (score 0):

**UNIVERSAL ADB DRIVER**

I have the same issue before, but i solved it easily by just following this steps:
-> connect your android phone in a debugging mode (to enable debugging mode goto settings -> About Phone -> Build Number(tap 7 times then it will be enable developer mode) in developer tools check USB debugging)

->download [Universal ADB Driver Installer](http://adbdriver.com/)

->choose Adb Driver Installer (Universal)

->install it

->it will automatically detect your android device(any kind of brand)

->chose the device and install.

Answer (score 0):

I made a tool, that should fix the problem, you just have to

1. connect the phone in USB Debugging mode to PC and run the tool.

Here is the link to the [repo](https://github.com/fawazahmed0/Latest-adb-fastboot-installer-for-windows)