# ADB doesn't list my Device

Tags: android, adb, device-manager

I'm trying to push an app from eclipse to my phone but adb doesn't work. It doesn't see my phone when I write 'adb devices'. First I thought it could be a problem of Cyanogen Unofficial Android 5.0, so I reverted to 4.4, but it doesnt work either. I followed an answer on this this question '[adb doesn't show nexus 5 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343014/adb-doesnt-show-nexus-5-device)' by installing the driver but the device manager tells me, that the driver isn't installed (Code 28). When I try to install it manually it doesn't work, neither uninstalling works.

Comment: Oh, and in the device manager it is listed as 'ADB Interface'

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 8.1 on a Surface Pro 3

Comment: the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972658/adb-driver-and-windows-8-1 are exhaustive

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Fixed it by doing to device manager
1. Find the ADB driver. If it shows the warning sign then click on update driver.
2. Choose to update the file locally yourself.
3. Browse the file. It always shows a **SAMSUNG COMPOSITE DRIVER**. Select that option and let it happen.
 Don't worry if your device is not Samsung. The same driver works for almost all devices. Mine is a YU Yureka with CM12.

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the device from Device Manager.
2. Rescan for hardware changes.
3. List item will show up with "Unknown driver" status.
4. Click on "Update Driver" and select /extras/google/usb_driver
   Device Manager will find the driver and warn you about installing it. Select "Yes." This time the device got installed properly.

[source] [Android device does not show up in adb list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170392/android-device-does-not-show-up-in-adb-list)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. After deleting the device and scanning for changes it is still recognized as ADB Interface. I don't know why...

Answer (score -1):

Try this tool when your device is connected.
--> http://adbdriver.com/

Normally it should list your device and notice it has a faulty driver. 
Hit the install button and it wil replace the faulty one with a working one.

[Source] Personal Experience

Comment: It says: '[Error] Incompatible with Win8 x64'

Comment: Is USB debugging enabled on the device?

Comment: Yes, of course... I think the problem is on Windows site.

Comment: That you have to look into yourself. Look for non-signed drivers of the manufacturer and install those with the signed driver protection off