# USB Debugging not working, adb ignores Nexus 7

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, nexus-7

For several weeks, I was able to connect my Nexus 7 2 to my computer running Windows 7, and Eclipse would recognize it, allowing me to run apps on it. The device also showed up when I ran the `adb devices` command. Every time I plugged the Nexus 7 into the computer, the tablet asked if I wanted to allow USB debugging at that time. (Oddly, it never asked me whether I wanted to always allow it from that computer, but I didn't care.)

I recently updated the tablet to Android 4.4.2. I also updated the Android SDKs through the Android SDK manager. Now, when I plug the tablet in, I do not get prompt about USB debugging on the tablet, and neither Eclipse nor adb can see that it is there.

Here is a list of things I tried to do, gathering ideas from various forums around the web.

- Re-download the Asus drivers for the Nexus 7 and update the driver. However, Windows does not even recognize this as the right drivers for this device.
- Turn USB Debugging off and on on the tablet, and also revoke all USB debugging permissions.
- Change the connection mode from media device to camera
- Switch the runtime from Dalvik to ART
- Type adb kill-server followed by adb start-server in the command line
- Delete eclipse and all the Android SDK and download them all over again

None of this worked. Any other ideas on what to try?

Comment: This is the perfect answer for your requirement http://stackoverflow.com/a/19839812/2567598

Comment: Thank you for finding that, but it does not work. I had tried this with the Asus driver. I would try it with the Google USB driver, as that answer suggested, but I cannot find it; Although I have downloaded the google usb driver through the sdk manager, there is no "google" folder under the extras folder.

Comment: I think you need to manually add your Nexus 7's detail like in that post described. I too did same.

Comment: I did manually add my device's details. No luck.

Comment: Oh ok, I guess you have some unique kind of problem. Lets see some other user with same error should help you out :)

Comment: I finally figured it out. You can see my solution below. Basically, I had to stop trying the driver for Asus and go find the Google USB driver. Thank you for helping me find the solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turns out that the Nexus 7 definitely needs the Google USB Driver. Finding, downloading, and installing this driver worked perfectly.

Because [Google's Android OEM drivers page](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) does not include the Nexus 7 in its list of devices that need the Google USB driver, I had been trying the driver from Asus, which did not work. I did not try the Google USB driver because for some reason my SDK manager said it had downloaded the driver, but the driver was not to be found.

Finally I found I could [download the Google USB driver from this page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html), which clarifies that all Google Nexus devices need this driver. Now I have successfully re-connected the tablet to ADB.

I submitted a [documentation bug report to Google here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65119&thanks=65119&ts=1390436681) in hopes that the OEM drivers page can be updated to reflect that all Google Nexus devices need the Google USB driver.

Comment: Good that you find it out your self :)

Comment: Per above, it's in this location: `\your_sdk_path\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

Answer (score 12):

Nexus 7 tablet with Android 4.4.4. Settings > Storage > USB Computer Condition.
Two checkboxes: MTP and PTP. Uncheck both.

Comment: Weirdly, i have two nexus 7's on 4.4.4, one of them wouldn't connect and one would. Both with MTP check. Unchecking MTP on the one that wouldn't work fixed it. Very odd.

Comment: You saved my life!

Answer (score 5):

With your phone disconnected

In windows explorer - right click computer, go to manage, in computer management find and uinstall device driver (under Android device)

Download new drivers from http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top

Connect the phone, windows will try to install new drivers, install drivers manually with drivers downloaded as above

The above worked for me

Answer (score 5):

For me, after updating to Android 4.4.2, it was critical that I connected the device as a Camera (PTP) rather than as a Media Device (MTP). Previously, before the update, I was able to connect as a Media Device (MTP).

Comment: I find this to be true as well for the 2012 N7

Comment: This solved the problem for Gigabyte GSmart Roma R2.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have not all needed drivers (PC can recognise your phone like usb device but debugging would not work). **I solved this problem in Android 4.4.4 by uncheking all items (MTP, PTP, UMS)** from menu: storage->USB computer connections and than **tick 'Media device(MTP)**. Now all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

thank you Arthur, I found Nexus 7 tab not working even after unchecking or checking. Problem solved by unchecking USB Debugging (under developer options).. settings>Developer option> USB debugging.  then check (put tick the MTP device):.storage->USB computer connections and than tick 'Media device(MTP)

Answer (score 1):

Complete checklist:

1. [Enable debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103117/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-nexus-7) onto the device
2. Select USB Connection as PTP (camera)
3. **Install [the driver](https://dl-ssl.google.com//android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip)** from http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Answer (score 0):

Before you try anything, make sure you update your Build related tools using your Android SDK Manager. Your adb might be outdated.