# Google Nexus 5 is not being detected by computer/doesn't appear in device manager

Tags: android, usb, device, device-driver

I have connected my mobile to my laptop via a USB cable, have turned on developer mode, debugging mode, MTP, and installed the google driver via the Eclipse "extras" folder in the SDK Manager. I have unplugged and replugged the device into every USB port on my computer, and am about to restart the PC as soon as I post this question.

However, given this too will not work, does anyone know how I can get my device to be detected without factory resetting? It's a friend's phone, so I can't have all his files wiped.

All help appreciated.

Comment: install driver for nexus 5 in your sysytem

Comment: **This is not the question** asked in the _as already has an answer_ link.  That one asks about drivers. A device that _isn't detected_ probably has a hardware or firmware problem.  It might not be serious, e.g. some "USB" cables are really only _charging_ cables. I'll post an answer on the [above linked page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838016/what-usb-driver-should-we-use-for-the-nexus-5/34301838#34301838). If this solves your problem, click over that page and give me an up-vote. k^]

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem after installing the driver, one answer from this question solved my problem
[What USB driver should we use for the Nexus 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838016/what-usb-driver-should-we-use-for-the-nexus-5/)

To get my nexus 5 recognized I changed the usb connection mode from MTP to PTP

Unplug the device from the computer
Go to Settings -> Storage.
In the ActionBar, click the option menu and choose "USB computer connection".
Check "Camera (PTP)" connection.
Plug the device and you should have a popup on the device allowing you to accept the computer's incoming connection, or something like that.
Finally, you should see it now in the DDMS and voilà.

Comment: So the device is detected, but now the drivers are out of date, and I have no idea how to update them.

Comment: I can't find the storage option in settings. But there is an option named Storage & USB. When I opened it and clicked option menu, I can't see any option like "USB computer connection". There is only one option "Help & Feedback". Current version is 6.0.

Comment: @berserk: You can find the option in "Developer Options -> Select USB Configuration"

Answer (score 4):

Solution is to open Android SDK Manager and download/install latest USB drivers (under Extras). Then in Windows Device Manager (devmgmt.msc), right click the Nexus 5 device and select Update Driver Software. Then, Browse my computer for driver software > Android SDK Dir > Extras > usb_driver

Comment: How do I update the driver from there? I use the files "amd64",  "i386" and ever "usb_driver" in the google file in extras, but all 3 are "unable to install".

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to turn USB debugging on/off/on for some reason it got confused. I'd recommend to restart Eclipse and the phone to make sure all works.

Answer (score 3):

You are using windows I guess. If yes go to device manager remove your old driver. It may be listed as Android phone or nexus. Then reconnect it. This solved my problem.

Comment: As in, select "uninstall" from the right click menu? I did this, and tried reconnecting it - It's detecting the device now, but there's still a yellow exclamation mark and I don't know how to update the driver.

Comment: download the driver extract it and on the device manager update the driver by right click and browse my computer for driver software its basic stuff man

Comment: Sorry, poor wording - The Google usb driver folder had two files in it - When I tried to update the driver using each of the files, then the usb_driver file, it was "unable to update" every time. But the guy's taken his phone back now, so it's too late anyway </3 Thanks for the help though!

Comment: just select the root folder and windows will take care of the rest